# Amazon pay redirection

Tags: amazon-pay

I'm trying to integrate my website with amazon pay redirect
as mentioned in the documentation in their website I follow the instuctions
as follow:

```
{
    "command":"AUTHORIZATION",
    "access_key": "xxxx", 
    "merchant_id": "xxx", 
    "merchant_reference": "Ahmad",
    "amount": 100,
    "currency": "EUR",
    "language": "us",
    "customer_email": "test@gmail.com",
    "signature": "4637c830d1386abf7374f2e694498c91dbf2517a28b61c42ae121f22fcc3f2a1",
    "order_description":"iphone"
}
```

but when I send a request by postman I get the following response with the same info +  "response_message": "Technical problem"

did I do something wrong? and how to solve this?
this is my first time with payment integration

documantion for redirect:
https://paymentservices-reference.payfort.com/docs/api/build/index.html#authorization-purchase-request

thank you

Comment: In the docs it says "access_code" instead of "access_key". This might already be part of the problem.

Comment: @marcus.kreusch Hello Marcus I edited it but unfortunately doesn't work

Comment: Please check the documentation, `merchant_id` is in fact `merchant_identifier`. There might be other issues with your payload.